# TSQL Error handling, getting SQL Query which triggered an error

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

I know these functions for handling an sql error

1. `ERROR_LINE()`
2. `ERROR_MESSAGE()`
3. `ERROR_NUMBER()`
4. `ERROR_PROCEDURE()`
5. `ERROR_SEVERITY()`
6. `ERROR_STATE()`

described here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179495(v=sql.105).aspx

but, is there a possibility to also get the sql **query string** which triggered an error ?

Comment: You have ERROR_LINE() that you can use to find the string.

Comment: Not that I know of through a built in function. If you were determined enough, you could use a custom error handler stored procedure and call that in your catch blocks to record errors and the associated sql/procedure name, but you would have to pass the executed sql through a variable so you could pass it to your error handler. [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server Part One (of Three) – Jumpstart Error Handling - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#error_handler_sp)